# How to link glibc to ld?

Tags: conda, ld, glibc

So I am getting this error when trying to compile a code.  Not sure where the link needs to go.

```
  /home/will/WRF/miniconda3/envs/ncl_stable/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/will/WRF/Libs/NETCDF/lib/libnetcdf.so: undefined reference to `pow@GLIBC_2.29'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

ldd --version outputs

> ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3) 2.35
> Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
> warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
> Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not sure where the link needs to go.

You should *never* use `ld` to link user-level programs on UNIX -- it is only ever appropriate to use `ld` when linking the OS kernel, or a boot loader.

For all other uses, you should use appropriate compiler driver, e.g. `gcc` or `g++`.

> `ldd --version` outputs

`ldd` version is *irrelevant* -- `ld` and `ldd` are totally different things.

---

Assuming you do actually use `gcc` to link your program, it's likely that you are missing `-lm`. Add it to the end of your link command line.